# Shell: print both variable name and value?

Tags: shell

Let's say I have a function called superEcho. I want it to print both the variable name and its value.

```sh
#!/bin/bash


function superEcho() {
    echo "${v_day}"
    echo '${v_day}'
}

v_day=20220101
superEcho ${v_day}

# output
# 20220101
# ${v_day}
```

From the code above, I can easily get the argument name "${v_day}" and its value.
However, what if I change the variable's name? Such as:

```
v_last_day=20211231
superEcho ${v_last_day}
```

This function won't work any more.
Can I change it to adapt to any variable name?

PS: this is a wrapper function, it won't ask users to change their code. For example, you can't pass the variable name as an argument:

```
superEcho "${v_day}" '${v_day}'
```

Comment: Seem like it's a mission impossible :(

Comment: Variable-expansion is NOT performed within single-quotes (e.g. `'${v_day}'`) You will need to pass the name and value to the function, (e.g. `superEcho v_day, "$v_day"`) and then `echo $1 $2`

Comment: Also, don't write `function` before the function, simply `superEcho() { [ -n "$1" ] && echo "$1"; [ -n "$2" ] && echo "$2"; }`

Answer (score 5):

Bash supports indirect [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) using `${!parameter}`, which you can use with the *name* of your variable:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

superEcho() { 
  echo "$1 = ${!1}"
}

v_day=20220101
superEcho v_day
```

(Note that your version of `superEcho` does not use the passed parameter, but prints `v_day` in any case.)

Comment: If your PS means that you can't change the `superEcho` calling code at all, then I agree with ruxtain: it's impossible to infer the name from a variable's value (at least not in general).

Comment: All versions of the Korn shell also support indirect expansion using namerefs. `zsh` supports indirect expansion similar to `bash`.  By the way, POSIX does not support indirect expansion; the workaround is to use `eval`,

Comment: You're right, @fpmurphy. I just gave the `bash` answer (still  wanting to point out that it's a `bash` feature) because the initial question had an `#!/bin/bash` script.